# Angular doesn't update my object after http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is my angular code:

```
samirsoftApp.controller("OrderCtrl",function($scope,$http){
$scope.currentStep=1;
$scope.defaultQuantity=1;
$scope.item={};
$scope.getItem = function(){
$http.get('/test/getItemDetails/')
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
$scope.$apply(function(){
$scope.item = data;
});
console.log($scope.item);
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
console.log(data)
});
};
});
```

when it request and get answer, it does not update my item object, so I used $apply and it did not work and throw an error: 
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
S/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:6:417
.....

I also tried

```
$timeout(function() {
$scope.item = data;
}, 0);
```

instead of $apply` but it prints a null object in consol

it's like this:

```
samirsoftApp.controller("OrderCtrl",function($scope,$http,$timeout){
$scope.currentStep=1;
$scope.defaultQuantity=1;
$scope.item={};
$scope.getItem = function(){
$http.get('/test/getItemDetails/')
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
$timeout(function() {
$scope.item = data;
}, 0);
console.log($scope.item);
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
console.log(data)
});
};
});
```

What should I do for my object to be updated after a http request.
thanks

Comment: Did the second thing you tried not work, with the timeout?

Comment: Are you sure that your Ajax request actually returns data? If you have console.log() inside the request, does that show anything?

Comment: no, it show a empty object in consol. why is that?

Comment: yes, I'm pretty sure about ajax request, it return a json, and fully tested

Comment: It looks like your endpoint doesn't actually return a value, have a look at your server code

Comment: When you put console log for 'data' in the callback?

Comment: In both scenarios (timeout or apply) you are setting telling it to set your scope.item *later*, and u actually print it to the console before it's even set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the data returned by `$http.get()` request like this

```
  $http.get('/test/getItemDetails/')
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.item = data;
      console.log($scope.item);
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  };
```

No need for `$apply` as angular automatically updates `$scope`

I suspect the problem is elsewhere with your code

Possibly:

- You defined `function#getItem` which contained the `$http` request but where did you call it?
- Make sure the call to URL `/test/getItemDetails/` is

  1. returning data by manually browsing or by using a utility like POSTMAN.
  2. being called with the proper URL - try checking in `developer tools >  network` for **404 Errors**

I have updated your code - demo **here** - http://jsbin.com/notudebiso/1/edit?html,js,output

(using a $http call to github api)